# @IBInspectable default values are not present in the Attribute Inspector

Tags: ios, swift

I got a simple `UIView` subclass that I'm trying to make `@IBInspectable`. Only trouble is I see `--` instead of default values in the attribute inspector.

```
  @IBInspectable var cornerSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    cornerSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    cornerSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
  }
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    cornerSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
  }
```

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

I assumed it would be `10`.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043981/how-to-set-default-values-for-ibinspectable-in-objective-c. As I understand it from the comments, this is not possible.